# NHibernate Criteria API - order by max of two properties

Tags: nhibernate, sql-order-by, nhibernate-criteria

I have a `PrivateMessage` class and I want to get list of PMs for user sorted chronologically either by `CreationDate` or `LastAnswerDate` (depending on which is more recent) using Criteria API.

How to sort by max of these two properies in Criteria API? My code looks similar to following:

```
var dc = DetachedCriteria.For<PrivateMessage>();
...
dc.AddOrder(new Order("???");
return (IList<PrivateMessage>)FindAll(typeof(PrivateMessage), dc);
```

`CreationDate` is `DateTime` and `LastAnswerDate` is `DateTime?`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Order.Desc(
    Projections.Conditional(
        Restrictions.GtProperty("CreationDate", "LastAnswerDate"),
        Projections.Property("CreationDate"),
        Projections.Property("LastAnswerDate"))))
```

Comment: Thanks :). I solved that by coalesce since one property is nullable but your solution will work always.